# How to publish split apk file on google play store

Tags: android, apk

I have gone through APK Splits Concept from this google doc.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-split

But I don't know how to publish(upload) Split APK file to Google Play Store.

Comment: Same as normal,  you do one upload per apk file.

Comment: It is uploaded as bundle now